# JS in Streamlit

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit

I am trying to convert the below snippet into Streamlit:

https://codepen.io/eshell/pen/ePZYaa

Here is what I have done so far, but the components do not display in Edge.

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

Please could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

# Custom CSS
custom_css = """
<style>
*, *::before, *::after { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#ui-container {
    background-color: #9EE04E;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
}

#ui-container h3, #ui-container h5 { text-align: center; }

.source-item {
    min-width: 8em;
    max-height: 2.4em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 1em;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: move;
}

.source-bag {
    background-color: #89c144;
    min-height: 11em;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.source-bag .source-item {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.map-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 26em;
}

.map-bag {
    margin-top: 1em;
    min-width: 20em;
    background-color: #89c144;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.map-bag header {
    position: relative;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 10em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.map-bag header.required::after {
    content: '*';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.map-bag .drop-zone {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 0.1em dashed #333;
    background-color: #a7d165;
}

.map-bag .drop-zone .source-item {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

#map-submit {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#map-submit button {
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media(max-width: 630px) {
    .map-list {
        max-height: none;
    }
}
</style>
"""

# HTML template
html_template = """
<div ng-app="MyApp" id="ui-container">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" class="header-mapper">
        <h3>The following headers were found in your uploaded CSV file.</h3>
        <h5>Drag & Drop to map your headers to the fields below!</h4>

        <drag-drop-mapper source="headerList" map="mapFieldList"></drag-drop-mapper>

        <div id="map-submit" ng-show="mapComplete === true">
            <button>Submit!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

# JavaScript code
javascript_code = """
var DragDropMapperModule = angular.module("dragDropMapperModule", [angularDragula(angular)]);

DragDropMapperModule.controller("dragDropMapperController", function ($scope, dragulaService) {
    dragulaService.options($scope, "dragbag", {
        revertOnSpill: true
    });

    $scope.addMapping = function ($dropSource, $target, $source) {
        if ($dropSource.hasClass('drop-zone')) {
            $scope.updateMapping($dropSource, $target, $source);
            return;
        }
        var targetIndex = $target.attr('data-index');
        var sourceIndex = $source.attr('data-index');
        $scope.map[targetIndex].mapValue = sourceIndex.toString();
    };

    $scope.updateMapping = function ($dropSource, $target, $source) {
        var dropSourceIndex = $dropSource.attr('data-index');
        var targetIndex = $target.attr('data-index');
        var sourceIndex = $source.attr('data-index');
        $scope.map[targetIndex].mapValue = sourceIndex;
        $scope.map[dropSourceIndex].mapValue = null;
    }

    $scope.removeMapping = function ($source) {
        var sourceIndex = $source.attr('data-index');
        $scope.map[sourceIndex].mapValue = null;
    };

    $scope.swapMapping = function ($target, $source, $existing, $sourceItem) {
        var targetIndex = $target.attr('data-index');
        var sourceIndex = $source.attr('data-index');
        var existingIndex = $existing.attr('data-index');
        var sourceItemIndex = $sourceItem.attr('data-index');
        $scope.map[targetIndex].mapValue = existingIndex;
        $scope.map[sourceIndex].mapValue = sourceItemIndex;
    };

    $scope.$on('dragbag.drop', function (e, el, target, source) {
        var $target = $(target);
        if ($target.hasClass('source-bag')) {
            $scope.removeMapping($(source));
        }
        else if ($target.children().length > 1) {
            $target.children().each(function () {
                if ($(this).html() !== $(el).html()) {
                    $(source).append($(this));
                }
            });
            $scope.swapMapping($target, $(source), $(el), $(source).find('.source-item'));
        } else {
            $scope.addMapping($(source), $target, $(el));
        }
        $scope.$emit('drag-drop-mapping-update', $scope.map);
    });
});

DragDropMapperModule.directive('dragDropMapper', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: { source: '=', map: '=' },
        controller: 'dragDropMapperController',
        template: [
            '<div class="drag-drop-mapper">',
                '<div dragula=\'"dragbag"\' class="source-bag">',
                    '<div class="source-item" ng-repeat="item in source track by $index" data-index="{{$index}}">',
                        '{{item.text}}',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="map-list">',
                    '<div class="map-bag" ng-repeat="item in map track by $index">',
                        '<header ng-class="{required: item.required === true}">{{item.text}}</header>',
                        '<div class="drop-zone" dragula=\'"dragbag"\' data-index="{{$index}}"></div>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {}
    };
});

var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['dragDropMapperModule']);

myApp.controller("MyController", function($scope, dragulaService) {
    $scope.mapComplete = false;

    // demo data (the headers parsed from an uploaded CSV file)
    $scope.headerList = [
        { id: 1,  text: 'FIRST_NAME'},
        { id: 2,  text: 'LAST_NAME' },
        { id: 3,  text: 'COMPANY_NAME' },
        { id: 4,  text: 'ADDRESS' },
        { id: 5,  text: 'CITY' },
        { id: 6,  text: 'COUNTY' },
        { id: 7,  text: 'STATE' },
        { id: 8,  text: 'ZIP' },
        { id: 9,  text: 'PHONE1' },
        { id: 10, text: 'PHONE2' },
        { id: 11, text: 'EMAIL' },
        { id: 12, text: 'WEB' }
    ];

    // demo data (the fields you want to map to)
    $scope.mapFieldList = [
        { id: 1, field: 'FirstName', text: 'First Name',    mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 2, field: 'LastName',  text: 'Last Name',     mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 3, field: 'Address1',  text: 'Address 1',     mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 4, field: 'Address2',  text: 'Address 2',     mapValue: null, required: false },
        { id: 5, field: 'City',      text: 'City',          mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 6, field: 'State',     text: 'State',         mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 7, field: 'Zip',       text: 'Zip',           mapValue: null, required: true },
        { id: 8, field: 'Phone',     text: 'Primary Phone', mapValue: null, required: false },
        { id: 9, field: 'Mobile',    text: 'Mobile Phone',  mapValue: null, required: false },
        { id: 10, field: 'Email',    text: 'Email Address', mapValue: null, required: true }
    ];

    $scope.$on('drag-drop-mapping-update', function(eventName, map) {
        console.log('New mapping: ', map);
        // determine if all required fields have been mapped
        var isComplete = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            if (map[i].mapValue === null && map[i].required === true) {
                isComplete = false;
            }
        }
        $scope.mapComplete = isComplete;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
});
"""


# Streamlit app
def main():
    st.title("Drag and Drop Mapper")

    # Inject custom CSS
    st.markdown(custom_css, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    # Render the HTML template
    components.html(html_template, height=600)

    # Run the JavaScript code
    components.html(f"<script>{javascript_code}</script>", height=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgJGx.png
```